# why does selenium ide not record when we move from 1 page to another?

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a feature to test. Here on page 1 i have to enter my username and password. then click on the login button. then the user is logged in and taken to a new page.
Selenium does not record anything once we move to a new page. I have to again open selenium in this new page and then strt recording if i want to.

This is stopping me from recording a complete flow.
is there any specific commands for selenium to read the new page an continue recording

PLease help me in this. how can i record

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you login, is it taking you to a new page in a new browser window or tab, or in the same window/tab?

Answer (score 0):

Instead try with Selenium Web-Driver, where you can do these kind of stuffs, 
for more info refer to this question on Stack Overflow -  "switch tabs using selenium Webdriver".

or you still want to achieve this with IDE?